# Is there a name for an anti-virus station / kiosk?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware, terminology, virus-removal

I am not able to define the exact term for a station that is meant to scan whatever media coming from outside a company and that have the following specifications:

- The station should never be on any network
- The station must be used to check any device (USB key, hard disk, etc...) that should further be connected on a network
- The station has to be manually updated (understand virus definitions)

Anyone know an exact term that refers to this? In French, the designation "station blanche" exists and is literally translated as "white station", but I'm not sure that the term applies.

Comment: A physical sandbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "[sheep dip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheep_dip_(computing))" station is one term - from the practice of dipping sheep in cleansing fluids before letting them near the rest of the flock.